# Equivalent Definition of Elliptic Symbols?

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations

A smooth function $a\in C^\infty(\mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R^n)$ is called an **elliptic symbol of order $m\in\mathbb R$** if there are real constants $C, R>0$ such that $$|\xi|\geq R\Rightarrow |\sigma(x, \xi)|\geq C(1+|\xi|)^m.$$

How can I show it is possible to replace $(1+|\xi|)^m$ by $|\xi|^m$?

These symbols appear frequently in the theories of (pseudo-)differential operators and the condition above is strong enough to assure some nice regularity properties in some functional spaces.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $m<0$ then $(1+|\xi|)^m<|\xi|^m$.

If $m\ge0$ and $|\xi|\ge1$ then
$$
(1+|\xi|)^m\le2^m\,|\xi|^m.
$$